# How can I test for changes in the distribution of categorical data over time?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, independence, chi-squared-test

Each week at my organization, we receive X number of type A messages, Y number of type B messages, Z number of type C messages...etc. I want to be able to test if the distribution of these message types for one week differs from the previous weeks (months, quarters...) message type distribution.

Am I right in assuming I can't simply do a chi-square test of independence here because of autocorrelation? What method could I employ to test if the distribution of messages in one week differed from prior weeks?

Comment: I'm not 100% but if your values are low, is it possible to use Fisher's exact test to compare each time-slice of data to each other and then as new weeks come in, add it to the computation?

Comment: Do you only want to test a particular week against the prior weeks, or did you want to test if there is a change in the composition of messages over time?

Comment: @gung - Ahh, but those 2 are not mutually exclusive [Commence throwing rotten fruit] :-)

Comment: @rolando2, they aren't necessarily, but I was thinking of a prior steady state & testing to see if this week was anomolous, which wouldn't be well represented by a slope, eg. That's what the description sounds like, but I wonder if what the OP really wants is to know if it is continuously changing over time.

Comment: The main goal is to test a particular week against prior weeks to see if one week is anomolous. Sorry I should have been more clear!

Comment: I would start plotting the data with some kind of control chart